# Org-mode: Can't display inline images when openwith-mode is turned on

Tags: org-mode, images, openwith

I use [`openwith`](https://bitbucket.org/jpkotta/openwith) to open images and a number of other types of files in external applications.

It works a treat, but gets in the way of displaying inline images in `org-mode` buffers: When I do <kbd>C-c C-x C-v</kbd> (`org-toggle-inline-images`) with `openwith-mode` turned on, the first image file linked in the current buffer is opened in an external viewer. The contents of the buffer itself don't change, i.e., no images are displayed inside the buffer.

**Q:** How can I stop `openwith-mode` from interfering with the display of inline images in `org-mode`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Internally, `org-toggle-inline-images` calls `org-display-inline-images` to handle display of inline images. You can [advise](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html) this function to turn off `openwith-mode` while it is doing its thing, and to turn it back on afterwards:

```el
(defadvice org-display-inline-images
  (around handle-openwith
          (&optional include-linked refresh beg end) activate compile)
  (if openwith-mode
      (progn
        (openwith-mode -1)
        ad-do-it
        (openwith-mode 1))
    ad-do-it))
```

With this in place, no external viewers are opened when doing <kbd>C-c C-x C-v</kbd> in an `org-mode` buffer containing inline images.

Comment: Was just about to suggest advice.  Might I suggest one modification to test whether or not `openwith-mode` is `t` before toggling it off and on?  With the current code, you would inadvertently turn on `openwith-mode` if it were off before you called `org-display-inline-images`.

Comment: @Dan Good idea, thanks! I modified the code accordingly.